# Load async YouTube API in to ReactJS application

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, reactjs

I need to load the YouTube JavaScript API which requires you to include a script tag with an onload query string which points towards a global callback function. Once the Google client is loaded the callback gets called:

```
<script>
function init() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey('465723722VeAji1ZVqYiJxB7oyMTVLI');
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
       YouTubeClientLoaded = true;
    });
} 
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
```

This all works fine in principle but I'm having a hard time working out how to integrate this global callback in to my ReactJS application. How can I tell react that the client is loaded and ready to use?

I've had a few thoughts but all seem hacky. I thought about starting the React app up and setting a timer that periodically checks for the existence of the `YouTubeClientLoaded` global variable (or the `gapi` object) or perhaps a pubsub mechanism so my global init function can emit when it's ready. Problem with the pubsub route is that the pubsub itself would also need to be global so then how do I get that communicating with React...

Is there a more correct way of achieving this?

Comment: And why can't you expose a callback function that calls render or setState into global namespace from React component?

Comment: Ok sounds like this is what I need but how do I introduce a callback function in to the global namespace from React? Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: If you only have one component that need that API you can introduce a global function placeholder beforehand (eg `window.onYoutubeApiLoaded = function(){}`) and overwrite that global it in your component constructor / mount handler - you will have `this` reference to the component by then. If you have several components using api, use pubsub the same way - subscribe from constructor / mount handler. A global callback is just a poor man's pubsub.

Comment: Hmm ok. How do you overwrite that in the component constructor then? How can I overwrite a global function placeholder from within a React component exactly? I would need to have several components using the API but how would I 'use pubsub in the same way'. The same way as what exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Global context is called global, because you can access it from anywhere, React components included.

Comment: Yes of course..but taking your idea gives me this: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/18080/ .The init function defined in the first script tag is always called...even if I do overwrite that from within react, so still React does not know when the API is loaded.

Comment: Okay, I see. 1. You absolutely have to render your top-level component somewhere with `ReactDOM.render`. Look up the details in React docs. `React.createClass` basically creates a new component type, not a component instance as something on the page. 2. api may be already loaded by the time your component instance is created and component should check that; so initial state would be something like `{youtubeAPILoaded: !!window.gapi}`

Comment: Great, after a bit of fiddling about I got a solution that worked. Most of the time the youtube api is loaded by the time the react component mounts but on throttling the connection the react version of init is called